# MySQL SELECT first entry of group PER group PER day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named worksheets_items similar to this set up

```
table "worksheet_items"
ID    DATE_ADDED    COUNTY_ID    NAME    COMPLETED
1     2016/03/15    11           "ZA"    0
2     2016/03/15    12           "FB"    1
3     2016/03/15    12           "GC"    0
4     2016/03/15    13           "GD"    1
5     2016/03/15    11           "EE"    1
6     2016/03/15    13           "TF"    1
7     2016/03/16    11           "YG"    0
8     2016/03/16    11           "WH"    0
9     2016/03/16    12           "YI"    1
10    2016/03/16    13           "QJ"    0
11    2016/03/16    13           "RK"    1
12    2016/03/16    12           "UL"    0
13    2016/03/16    11           "PM"    1
```

All I'm trying to do is get the one row (doesn't matter if it's first or not) per county per date. My goal is to display the date and every county under that date that has any entries that COMPLETED = 0

So in this case I would want to end up with

```
ID    DATE_ADDED    COUNTY_ID    NAME    COMPLETED
1     2016/3/15     11           "ZA"    0
3     2016/3/15     12           "GC"    0
7     2016/3/16     11           "YG"    0
12    2016/3/16     12           "UL"    0
10    2016/3/16     13           "QJ"    0
```

I tried using a GROUP BY but my expertise in MySQL is limited so it ended up just throwing errors out the wazoo. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you not just want WHERE completed = 0 ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I need one entry **per** county_id **per** date where completed = 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get one ID per date and county (e.g. the maximum ID). Then access the records with the IDs thus found.

```
select *
from worksheet_items
where (date_added, county_id, id) in
(
  select date_added, county_id, max(id)
  from worksheet_items
  where completed = 0
  group by date_added, county_id
)
order by id;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `GROUP_BY`at all

what you need is ordering records by date_added and county_id

```
SELECT * FROM worksheet_items
WHERE completed=0
ORDER BY date_added, county_id
```

- [Sorting Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)
- [Group By Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)